# ExoPlayer recreates after screen rotation in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-rotation, exoplayer

In my App, I have fragment in which I, alongside with other, play video in ExoPlayer. I set it up as simple as possible and the player itself works flawlessly, even with media session.
But the problem is that on device rotation, the video loads again in background (there seems to be two layers - one standard, functioning normally, loading video and playing it; and second layer in background. I can hear the sound of the video shortly after the activity recreates.
I am stopping and releasing the player and media session, but it didn't help.

MediaFragment.java

```
public class StepViewFragment extends Fragment implements Player.EventListener{

//vars


public StepViewFragment() {
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
//attach callbacks for buttons
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_step_view, container, false);

    //Bind view ButterKnife
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    //get Step from Bundle
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        step = bundle.getParcelable(AppConstants.STEP_BUNDLE_KEY);
        recipe = bundle.getParcelable(AppConstants.RECIPE_BUNDLE_KEY);
    }

    mainHandler = new Handler();

//...
//setup ui
//...

    if (step.videoURL.equals("")) {
        mediaCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        playVideo();
        initMediaSession();

    }

    return rootView;
}

public void initMediaSession (){
    mExoPlayer.addListener(this);

    mMediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getContext(), TAG);
    mMediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS);
    mMediaSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(null);

    mStateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE | PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE
            );
    mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build());
    mMediaSession.setCallback(new MySessionCallback());
    mMediaSession.setActive(true);
}

public void playVideo() {

    if (mExoPlayer == null) {

        DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector();
        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

        RenderersFactory renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(getContext());

        mExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(renderersFactory, trackSelector, loadControl);
        mPlayerView.setPlayer(mExoPlayer);

        String videoUrl = step.videoURL;

        Uri mp4VideoUri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);

        String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(getContext(), "BakingApp");

        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getContext(), userAgent);

        ExtractorMediaSource.Factory mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory);

        mExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource.createMediaSource(mp4VideoUri));
        mPlayerView.hideController();
        mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

}

public void releasePlayer() {
    mExoPlayer.stop();
    mExoPlayer.release();
    mExoPlayer = null;
    mMediaSession.release();
    mPlayerView = null;
}


@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (mExoPlayer != null) {
        releasePlayer();
    }
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (mExoPlayer != null) {
        releasePlayer();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mExoPlayer != null) {
        releasePlayer();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    if (mExoPlayer != null) {
        releasePlayer();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mExoPlayer != null){
        releasePlayer();
    }
}

@Override
public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest, int reason) {

}

@Override
public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

}

@Override
public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

}

@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
    if ((playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) && playWhenReady) {
        mStateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, mExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), 1f);

    } else if ((playbackState == Player.STATE_READY)){
        mStateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED, mExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition(), 1f);

    }

    mMediaSession.setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build());
    Log.d("HOVNOOOO", "Playback State Changed");
}

@Override
public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

}

@Override
public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

}

@Override
public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

}

@Override
public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

}

@Override
public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

}

@Override
public void onSeekProcessed() {

}


private class MySessionCallback extends MediaSessionCompat.Callback {
    @Override
    public void onPlay() {
        mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...
I was using `add()` to create the Fragment, so on rotation it added new one.
Using `replace` instead solved the problem.